# Are $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times \{0\}$ and the unit circle minus the North pole ambient isotopic in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$: the unit circle at the origin minus the North pole $C:=S^{1}-\{(0,1)\}$, and the subset of the $x$-axis $J:=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\times\{0\}$.

Let $i$ denote the inclusion embedding of $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and let $f$ denote an embedding of $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with image $J$ (for example, $f$ may be defined by composing the stereographic projection mapping $C$ onto the $x$-axis via the North pole with the map $(\arctan(-),0)$. That is, $f(x,y)=(\arctan(x/1-y),0)$).

Are $i$ and $f$ ambient isotopic embeddings? If they are not, is there an ambient homeomorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping $C$ onto $J$, i.e. such that $g\circ f = i$?

For the definitions of ambient isotopic embeddings and ambient isotopic subspaces see [this](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/ambient-isotopic-embeddings-on-topological-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are $i$ and $f$ ambient isotopic embeddings? If they are not, is there an ambient homeomorphism $g$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ mapping $C$ onto $J$, i.e. such that $g\circ f = i$?

No homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ maps $C$ onto $J$. That's because homeomorphisms preserve closures, but $\overline{C}=S^1$ is not homeomorphic to $\overline{J}=[-\pi/2,\pi/2]\times\{0\}$.

For this reason these cannot be ambient isotopic. This is a nice example, bacause these embeddings are (just) isotopic.

Comment: Thank you, they are indeed isotopic. In this other case (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3372635/ambient-isotopy-of-the-plane-carrying-unit-circle-minus-north-pole-onto-the-x) the embeddings $i$ and $f$ in the 1st answer become ambient isotopic when working in the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, as the images of the embeddings are each a great circle minus a point. My question was motivated by trying to find two isotopic embeddings of the circle minus a point that would not become ambient isotopic after performing the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.